# Comparing orientations with Postgres/PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm working on an app where we need to take the orientation of the user's phone (e.g. using the [web orientation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation) or otherwise), and compare it to a stored orientation. We then need to determine if these orientations are close enough to each other in terms of degrees.
Edit: The end goal of this is to tell when the user is facing in the exact same direction as what is stored in the database (i.e. the tilt isn't important)

So conceptually we're finding the distance between two points on a circle, but these points are determined by two angles, alpha and beta, rather like latitude and longitude, but they're both out of 360 degrees (like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231221/great-arc-distance-between-two-points-on-a-unit-sphere) I suppose). The web API returns three different angles alpha, beta and gamma, explained [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/#toc-events), but I only care about alpha and beta I think.

**Firstly, how do I store a 3d orientation in Postgres?** I could model this data as a [POINT](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5SVN/ST_MakePoint.html) with latitude and longitude, but it would be annoying to have to convert an angle out of 360 into an angle out of 180 or 90). Is there a better format to store orientation with in Postgres?

**Secondly, how do I compare orientations?** I've found this function, [ST_Distance_Spheroid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html), which compares the distance between points on a sphere in terms of latitude and longitude, but not only does that require converting my angles into latitude and longitude, but it also requires a spheroid to use for the mapping. Would that spheroid be a unit sphere? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: ii think you need to save 3 numbers (angles).  the sum of the absolute difference between all 3 would be the comparison.  The smallest comparison would be the orientation that is closest.  i'm just thinking out loud here, but, i don't think storage of a point, or projection of a point on a sphere helps (that's only two angles). maybe a sphere projections and a compass heading? this is a cool problem :-)

Comment: Well I don't think I need the gamma rotation for my situation because I'm interested in comparing where the user is *facing* with their phone. I'm less interested with the tilt. Which is why I think latitude and longitude might make sense

Comment: If you just need facing wouldn't that be the z axis alone? sounds like you want a compass heading.  if that's the case, then store the alpha channel. The query gets real simple then.  Weird things might happen with a compass heading if the phone is flipped upside down, I can see that you might want to use the beta value as a threshold to flip the compass heading (for an upsidedown phone).  I don't know, but, it seems like the angle alone should work.

Comment: But it's not just facing in the alpha plane, it's in beta as well -  how much they're looking up. I just don't consider gamma to be part of the 'facing'

Comment: It requires a bit of trigonometry to convert 2D (lat, lon) to 3D (x, y, z). See [where this is done internally](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/4b92e71d1c2a06d8c03f87546debf3fc61915c29/liblwgeom/lwgeodetic.c#L352), which can be written to a function for SQL.